# Flutter New Project Buile Error 18 Problem

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, project

I just new. when I created new flutter project, it show 18 error:
[that just always happen, but not at the first time I installing flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgieC.png)

I also check the flutter doctor and there is no problem. Hope u can solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried running `flutter pub get`?

Comment: I do, but still error

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to File --> Project Structure (crtl+alt+shift s) -->
In the Project ,Modules section choose the sdk (android api) then
Go to File --> Invalidate Cashes/Restart

Comment: Thanks, but there's no project structure in VSCode and that shortcut doesn't work

Comment: try to run flutter pub get

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using a old version of the sdk (no null safety), so you can remove the ? after key parameter ou comment the line 8

Comment: thanks for yours help. I just reinstalling flutter include its path and its work!! thank you very much